# "Click" on anchor tag

Tags: html, vba, click, anchor

EDIT 2: SOLVED.  I had to directly navigate to the src link in the iFrame... Thanks for all the help, you guys!

I've been trying to figure out how to click on the "Download Table" button from the website http://war-on-ice.com/playertable.html ... relevant HTML code below:

```
    <a class="btn shiny-download-link shiny-bound-output" id="downloadData" href="session/3d9eec9b00fc33032587b8b094e0a7b8/download/downloadData?w=" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
      Download Table
    </a>
```

When I click the button, it will download a .CSV file but the url changes every time the page is refreshed, so I can't navigate directly to the url.

I've tried a bunch of codes and have been googling for a couple days... it seems that the button is actually an Anchor (from what I can tell.. I'm not too experienced with coding).  This is the VBA code I have so far:

```
    Sub ClickDownload()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
        IE.Navigate ("http://war-on-ice.com/playertable.html")
        IE.Visible = True

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 'READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    For i = 0 To IE.Document.All.Length - 1 'lists through all elements on web page'
        If IE.Document.All(i).ID = "downloadData" Then 'if anchor id is "downloadData"
            IE.Document.All(i).Click 'then click on it'
        End If
    Next i

    End Sub
```

The code opens the website, but nothing happens after that (it never finds a match for the If Statement).

Any help on this would be awesome.  Thanks!

EDIT: I think this is inside an iframe, which might be causing a problem?

Comment: I think a more important question would be why does a page that has 2.4MB take 13 seconds to load?!?!?!?!